# Can electric field exist at constant electric potential

Tags: electric-fields

Like any charge body we take in constant electric potential are where E exist are not

Comment: The statement of the question is not intelligible to me.

Comment: $$dV = E.dx$$ $$V = Ed$$

Answer (score 1):

No.  The electric field $\vec E$ is the negative gradient of the potential:
$$
\vec E=-\vec\nabla V=\hat x\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}+\hat y\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}+\hat z\frac{\partial V}{\partial z}\, .
$$
(In one-dimension, this would be $E=-dV/dx$.) If the potential is constant, all its derivatives are $0$ and thus $\vec E$ is $0$.

Note that the other way around is possible, i.e. it is possible to have constant (or $0$) field but non-zero potential.  An example would be the field inside a conducting sphere, which must be $0$; the potential inside the sphere would be constant and equal to the potential on the surface of the sphere, which need not be $0$.